# Trouble getting jScrollpane to work on my site

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am attempting to use Kelvin Luck's JScrollPane on my website, but am having some trouble getting it to work.

Specifically, I tried to copy the coding for the simple horizontal scrolling function from the sample page here, but obviously missed something:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrows.html

Here is the page I am testing it on:

http://lowhandicapper.com/members/chipping-playlist-test/

There are 7 total videos in my playlist, but I can't get the scroll to function to show the 3 that are initially hidden.

**Update:**

I also created a test page using the same html for the horizontal slider from the first link above and put that on my site here:

[lowhandicapper.com/members/exact-horizontal-test/](http://lowhandicapper.com/members/exact-horizontal-test)

Still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your HTML markup.

You don't need to create all the .jspcontainer, .jspHorizontalBar, etc.
Jscrollpane does it for you.

Also, when you initialize your `.jScrollPane()` function use `jQuery` instead of `$` For some reason it's not working... maybe you have conflicts with another framework.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows: true});
});
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dVXZz/)

You'll just need to update the container width.

Comment: also, what's up with giving an ID to a script tag?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I made that change but I still can't get it to work :/ Also, not sure about the ID tag in the script, I copied that from that JScrollPane demo page: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrows.html

Comment: AMAZING! Thanks so much... literally had spent 2 days on that and now it's working great. You rock!

Comment: @AaronStackhouse Glad I could help. If you could mark this answer as accepted, I would greatly appreciate it.